# How do I upload files to google drive automatically from raspberry pi or from PUTTY

Tags: pi-3, ssh, terminal

The title says it all. I want a simple way to preferably automatically upload files from my pi to a google drive or something similar

Comment: https://medium.com/@annissouames99/how-to-upload-files-automatically-to-drive-with-python-ee19bb13dda

Comment: https://rclone.org/ is a command line utility that you can use to copy files to/from Google Drive.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this in multiple ways, the first one to pop up in my head is to use a GDrive terminal client like https://github.com/nurdtechie98/drive-cli (Python) or https://github.com/odeke-em/drive (Go).

You could set up a folder and use a cronjob to call the push method for example.

To set this up using the Python client you need to:

- Login using the client
- Create a directory in Google Drive
- Run `drive clone <GOOGLE_DRIVE_ID>`
- Create a cronjob running something like `cd /path/to/drive/folder && drive push`

This way you can push files every hour, minute, or second.

Answer (score 0):

I use `rclone` to make incremental backups of my Pi to Google Drive every 10 hours.

You can install it with `sudo apt install rclone`, but I prefer to get the latest version, so I install the ARM 32 .deb from the [rclone downloads page](https://rclone.org/downloads/).

After that run `rclone config` in a terminal. You can see how to setup Google Drive [here](https://rclone.org/drive/).

After that you can copy stuff to Google Drive using rclone using a command like this:

```
rclone copy /home/pi/testfile.bin "Google Drive:folder1/folder2/testfile.bin"
```

See more on the copy command [here](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_copy/).